# how to do finetune using pre-trained model in tf.estimator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

i got a model converted from caffe by using MMDNN tool, it converted the caffe model into a saved_model tensorflow style. it's a resnet18 model, and i just strip out several layers in the last, i wish i could load this architecture in the model_fn in a tf.estimator, and manually add some extra layers to do my job.
As the tutorial recommended that I could use loader.load method to load the saved_model. But i just want to use it in a estimator, and i need to define the architecture in the model_fn function. I searched out the SO and github but there isn't a very specific workflow to do that thing, somebody could help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of fine tuning using tf.Estimator:

1. Define your model using the SAME variable names/scopes as in your saved model
2. Use tf.estimator's warm start functions to initialize your new model with the saved weights. Here is a code snippet :

   ```
   if fine_tuning:
       ws = tf.estimator.WarmStartSettings(ckpt_to_initialize_from=path_saved_model,
                                           vars_to_warm_start='.*')
   else:
       ws = None

   estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_function,
                                               warm_start_from=ws,
                                               ...
                                               )
   ```

This will initialize any variable that share names between your currently defined graph and the saved model.

Comment: sorry about the delayed replying, thanks for your answer, but I recently droped the idea of using Estimator , I used the basic tf.import_meta_graph() API for alternative. The reason I changed to the basic APIs is that I want to directly import the graph from the checkpoint file( i used loader method import the .pb file first, then output a checkpoint file,, i really don't know how to manipulate .pb file). Then it works out, I found the tensor by graph.get_tensor_by_name() method to get the tensor from the feature layer and add some extra layers to do my task.